# R: how to insert a column with set of different dates

Tags: r, date

I have a list of all vacation days range. How can I insert them all along with the **days between** each start and end date into one list.

This is the dates list:

```
| start_date | end_date  |             
| 1/19/2017  | 2/4/2017  |                
| 3/30/2017  | 4/8/2017  |             
| 5/18/2017  | 9/16/2017 |                
| 9/24/2017  | 9/24/2017 |   # << 1 day only

Vacation_dates1 <- seq(as.Date("2017-1-19"),as.Date("2017-2-4"),by="days")  
Vacation_dates2 <- seq(as.Date("2017-3-30"),as.Date("2017-4-8"),by="days")  
Vacation_dates3 <- seq(as.Date("2017-5-18"),as.Date("2017-9-16"),by="days")  
Vacation_dates4 <- as.Date("2017-9-24")
```

I want the output to be all the dates into one list, not in 4 different list,

Comment: Convert them to actual Dates and use `?seq`

Comment: I used seq on the first set of dates but how can I combine all of them together into one list?

Comment: 1) please include the code you've tried in the question (use edit button), 2) please include the expected output for the input sample.

Comment: I updated it, I hope its clear now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you run this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)


# importing your data
df <- read_table(" start_date  end_date  
 1/19/2017   2/4/2017                  
 3/30/2017   4/8/2017               
 5/18/2017   9/16/2017                 
 9/24/2017   9/24/2017  ")

# parsing dates
df$start_date <- mdy(df$start_date)
df$end_date <- mdy(df$end_date)

# loop
period_days <- NULL
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  period_days[[i]] <- seq(df$start_date[i],df$end_date[i],by="days")
}

# code
result <- df %>% 
  mutate(duration=period_days)
```

your get this:

```
# Output
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  start_date end_date      duration    
  <date>     <date>        <list>      
# 1 2017-01-19 2017-02-04 <date [17]> 
# 2 2017-03-30 2017-04-08 <date [10]> 
# 3 2017-05-18 2017-09-16 <date [122]>
# 4 2017-09-24 2017-09-24 <date [1]>
```

you can extend the lists with

```
result %>% pull(duration)
```

and can apply `length` functions or whatever you want to do with it.

Comment: Hi Stephan, thanks for your reply, what I want is to have all the dates along with the dates between them, so my output will be for example:"2017-01-19" "2017-01-20" "2017-01-21" "2017-01-22" "2017-01-23" "2017-01-24" "2017-01-25" "2017-01-26"
 "2017-01-27" "2017-01-28" "2017-01-29" "2017-01-30" "2017-01-31" "2017-02-01" "2017-02-02" "2017-02-03"
 "2017-02-04"  , I think I got the answer, thanks for assisting me with your code,